# from InputStream to List<String>, why java is allocating space twice in the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am currently trying to process a large txt file (a bit less than 2GB) containing lines of strings.
I am loading all its content from an `InputStream` to a `List<String>`. I do that via the following snippet :

```
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipInputStream))) {
        List<String> data = reader.lines()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
```

The problem is, the file itsef is less than 2GB, but when I look at the memory, the JVM is allocating twice the size of the file :

[image]

Also, here are the heaviest objects in memory :

[image]

So what I Understand is that Java is allocating twice the memory needed for the operation, one to put the content of the file in a byte array and another one to instanciate the string list.

My question is : can we optimize that ? avoid having twice the memory size needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** `String` objects can take 2 bytes per character.

**The long answer**: conceptually a `String` is a sequence of `char`. Each `char` will represent one Codepoint (or half of one, but we can ignore that detail for now).

Each codepoint tends to represent a character (sometimes multiple codepoints make up one "character", but that's another detail we can ignore for this answer).

That means that if you read a 2 GB text file that was stored with a single-byte encoding (usually a member of the ISO-8859-* family) or variable-byte encoding (mostly UTF-8), then the size in memory in Java can easily be twice the size on disk.

Now there's a good amount on caveats on this, primarily that Java can (as an internal, invisible operation) use a single byte for each character in a `String` *if and only if* the characters used allow it (effectively if they fit into the fixed internal encoding that the JVM picked for this). But that didn't seem to happen for you.

What can you do to avoid that? That depends on what your use-case is:

1. Don't use `String` to store the data in the first place. Odds are that this data is actually representing some structure, and if you parse it into a dedicated format, you might get away with way less memory usage.
2. Don't keep the whole thing in memory: more often then not, you don't actually *need* everything in memory at once. Instead process and write away the data as you read it, thus never having more than a hand-full of records in memory at once.
3. Build your own string-like data type for your specific use-case. While building a full string replacement is a massive undertaking, if you know what subset of features you need it might actually be a quite surmountable challenge.
4. try to make sure that the data is stored as compact strings, if possible, by figuring out why that's not already happening (this requires digging deep in to the details of your JVM).

Comment: Thanx for your answer, indeed, I think the JVM didn't pick a compact encoding for my case. knowing that the content is exclusively MD5 hashs (a hash in each line).

Comment: 1. String seems the less complicated data structure to me.
2. Well, I tried that, memory wise, it's pretty efficient. It uses low memory, with like 500k chunks or so. but the problem is, I need to compare each line of the chunk with another 40million data I have in a PostgreSql database. when I do that with the stream open, well it's it only compares like 2M data, very weird behaviour... with all the 2GB in memory, it goes well.

Comment: Then we have a classic case of a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Explain what kind of comparison you need to do with the data set in the DB, then maybe we can suggest some kind of optimization. But that should probably go into a new question, since it would change this one quite massively.

Comment: If every line is a MD5 hash, then storing the whole thing as numbers is probably way more efficient. MD5 is 4 bytes (so could be stored in a `byte[4]` or even all of them in one huge `byte[]`, so the memory requirement per line would be roughly 4 bytes), while a String-representation of MD5 is at least 16 bytes for the `char[]` + a few bytes for other fields of `String` + object header size (and even the compact encoding just reduces the initial 16 to 8). So even a dedicated `MD5Hash` class with two `long` fields would be more efficient.

Comment: Assuming the usual form of MD5 hashes, i.e. hexadecimal numbers, the strings *are* stored in a compact form. The question’s screenshot clearly shows that the strings use `byte[]` arrays instead of `char[]` arrays. So, assuming there’s no white-space in the strings, you need 32 bytes for the actual character data, plus an object header (typically 12 bytes) and the array length (another 4 bytes). Makes 48 bytes for each array, which is in the order of magnitude shown in the screenshot. The string instances need another 24 bytes per object, also matching the screenshot. Raw MD5s need *16 bytes*.